# Windows 11 doesn't use HBRUSH passed by WM_CTLCOLORDLG. Is there a workaround for this?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-11

I am developing a dark-themed [property page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/property-sheets-and-property-pages). I have subclassed the windows procedure of the [property page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/property-sheets-and-property-pages) and I have handled WM_CTLCOLORDLG to return a dark-colored brush,

```
  case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:{
     HDC hdc = HDC(wParam);
     static LGuiSolidBrush brBack(LCOLOR_DARKTHEME_GRAY);
     SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
     return BOOL(brBack.hBrush);
  } break;
```

But for some reason, Windows 11 doesn't use the HBRUSH passed by WM_CTLCOLORDLG.
I found an article, https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/10299

it says that there is a new material called Mica that manages the painting of the apps background but I have limited knowledge how to bypass this programmatically. Need help. Thanks.

PS: It works well on lower versions of Windows

Comment: There is something wrong with your dialog procedure.  It must return INT_PTR, not BOOL.  As written, it cannot correctly return a GDI handle in 64-bit mode.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc

Comment: I also have the same problem. It is something with windows 11 and property sheets, as exactly the same WM_CTLCOLORDLG handler code works for all dialogs except for those inside property sheets